# Delete numbers from filename

Tags: shell, unix

I have a bunch of file names of the type:

```
a-1.001.txt
a-2.234.txt
a-3.765.txt
```

and so on. I want them to be:

```
a-1.txt
a-2.txt
a-3.txt
```

This is all in unix. I've been trying with "rename" but I can't get it to work with regular expressions. (I've read there are two versions and I probably have the other one).

Comment: What should happen if `a-1.001.txt` and `a-1.002.txt` exist in the same directory?

Comment: @pilcrow that doesn't happen. I put a 1, but they're dates and there's a file per date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $(ls) ; do   mv $i $(echo $i | awk -F '.' '{print $1"."$3}'); done
```

For testing change `mv` to `echo`.

PS: Did the code from my head, but should work. =)

Comment: You are missing a `;` before `done`. If you want to pipe the contents of `i` to `awk` then you should `echo` it, as the command `$i` means nothing. You forgot to append `.txt` to the file name. Also, you'll want to use `$(ls)` instead of `ls`, or even better, `$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*.txt")`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know how to create a loop to iterate over all the file names (or that you are going to do this manually) and that, for each file, its name is stored in `FILE`:

```
mv $FILE ${FILE%%.*}.txt
```

The `${parameter%%pattern}` idiom is [standard shell syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for removing the longest suffix matching *pattern*.